# Finding sufficient conditions for maximum local, minimum local and saddle point.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

**Question.** Let $f(x, y) = px^{2} + 2qxy + ry^{2}$ be, where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are constants. Find sufficient conditions on $p$, $q$ and $r$ so that the point $(0, 0)$ is the only point where $\nabla f = 0$ and

(i) $f (0, 0)$ is a local maximum;

(ii) $f (0, 0)$ is a local minimum;

(iii) $f(0, 0)$ is a saddle point.

By definition we have that the quadratic form associated with the hessian matrix $Hf(a)$ is given by $$H(a)(u) = Hf(a)(u,u) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{m} u_{i}u_{j} \frac{\partial^{2}f(a)}{\partial x_{j} \partial x_{i}}.$$ Where

$\sim \ H(a)$ is positive if $H(a)(u) > 0, \ \forall \ u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ whith $u \neq 0$;

$\sim \ H(a)$ is negative if $H(a)(u) < 0, \ \forall \ u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ whith $u \neq 0$;

$\sim \ H(a)$ is undefined if exists $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $H(a)(u) > 0$ and $H(a)(v) < 0$ whith $u \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$.

I intend to apply the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open and $a \in A$ critical point of the $C^{2}$ class function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$.

(i) If $H(a)$ is positive, then $a$ is a local minimum point of $f$;

(ii) If $H$ is negative, then $a$ is a local maximum point of $f$;

(iii) If $H$ is undefined, then $a$ is neither local minimum nor local maximum.

I know that $Hf(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix}
    2p & 2q \\
    2q & 2r \\
\end{bmatrix} $ such that $$Hf(0,0)(u,u) = \begin{bmatrix}
    u_{1} & u_{2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    2p & 2q \\
    2q & 2r \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    u_{1}\\
    u_{2}\\
\end{bmatrix} = 2u^{2}p + 4uvq + 2v^{2}r.$$

I find it difficult to see conditions in which the quadratic form is defined as positive, negative or indefinite. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's first handle the first order condition.

$$\nabla f=0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2p & 2q \\ 2q & 2r\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence we need the determinant to be non-zero since we want it to be the unique stationary point. That is $$ pr-q^2\ne 0$$

There are other conditions that are easier to check for [positive definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).

To be positive definite, all leading principal minors are positive, hence immediately, we can conclude that we just need $p>0$ and $pr-q^2>0$.

To be negative definite, its negative is positive definite. Hence we need $p<0$ and $pr-q^2>0$.

If it is neither positive definite nor negative definite, then it is $pr-q^2<0$.